# nodejs - Error: spawn ENOENT while adjusting image size using module gm

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I am trying to create a thumbnail with an image that I have already saved. I am using the module `gm` to adjust the size of the image.

```
var gm = require ('gm');
var fs = require('fs');
var savedphoto = "./testphoto.jpeg";
var testdir = "./testoutput.jpeg";
gm(savedphoto)
    .resize(100, 100)
    .noProfile()
    .write(testdir, function (err) {
        console.error (err);
    });
```

When I run this I get the error spawn `ENOENT`.

```
code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn.
```

How would I fix this problem?

Comment: ENOENT means `Error NO ENTry`. The problem occurs when it tries to write, check your permissions

Comment: Or when a certain cache is full.

Answer (score 7):

Replace:

```
var gm = require('gm');
```

for

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. By default, gm expects to use the graphicsmagick library instead of imagemagick. In my case, changing folder permissions had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Recipe for MacPorts users only (based on @RevNoah notice):

```
sudo port install GraphicsMagick
```

It will install GraphicsMagick library.